# Delphi XE5 TStopWatch hangs in Android

Tags: android, delphi, indy, firemonkey

Is there any known issues with TStopWatch in Delphi under Android?
My app that has been working fine under iOS is locking up when I create a TStopWatch.
I am doing this after a IdTelnet connect to provide a timeout.

```
IdTelnet1.Connect;
sw := TStopWatch.Create; // LOCKUP
sw.Start;
while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000) and (not IdTelnet1.Connected) do
  Sleep(20);
sw.Stop;
```

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: I have doubts about your diagnosis. The rest of Indy tends to use *blocking* operations. Are you sure the call to `Connect` has actually returned yet? I suspect it already has a built-in timeout mechanism.

Comment: Lines 2 and 3 of your program are more concisely written as a single line: `sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;`

Comment: If I put a breakpoint on the TStopWatch line it will stop there. Press F8 to continue and it never gets to the next line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using TStopWatch.StartNew. I have changed the code to this but have the same problem.

Comment: @Martin Of course it changes nothing. It's just more concise. Another piece of advice. If you think the problem is `TStopWatch`, then why is there Indy code in the question, and why is the question tagged Indy. Surely your SCCEE is a one liner, `sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;` You should edit the question so that it has the absolute bare minimum.

Comment: Also, surely the component doesn't force you to run a polling loop like that. Surely that's not the way to implement a wait until connection.

Comment: `Connect()` is a blocking method. It does not exit until the connection is established, and it raises an exception if it fails. If `Connected()` returns false after `Connect()` exits without an error, then the socket was connected and then disconnected, and is not automatically re-connected.  So this code makes no sense.  If you want a timeout on `Connect()` then use the `ConnectTimeout` property.

Comment: I added all of the code as I suspected that the Telnet connection might be somehow influencing this. 
I had originally assumed that the Connect blocked until finished. I would not have added this Wait code in my first cut so I suspect that I found I needed to do this for the iOS version.

Comment: If you take the Indy code out and TStopwatch works fine then it looks like TStopWatch is good. Indy works the same on iOS so the looping is wrong there too.

Comment: If I take out the Telnet connect the Stopwatch does not lock up. I think I have bigger problems with Indy not working the same under Android. This is definitely not a re-target and build exercise as promised by Embarcadero. Back to basics.

Comment: Which part of `telnet.connect is a blocking function` did you not understand, it's the same in iOS, Android, Windows etc. Perhaps the connection (which comes up fine under iOS) does not connect under Android, due to reasons beyond this code sample.

Comment: @Martin: it would seem your question should be: "why doesn't Indy Telnet make a connection on Android?". It would seem to me the TStopwatch component has nothing to do with it. Does your app have the appropriate permissions to set up a telnet connection?